# Converting HTML Website to React - Issue loading my external JS file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mobile, navbar

I am attempting to convert my test website from HTML to React, so that I can communicate with my AWS API Gateway, Lamda function and DynamoDB.

I have 90% working now and I am able to create users, and login via my new React Website, however, I am having an issue with loading a script file which I use to control my navbar during mobile viewer.  This previous worked in my HTML site.

The issue is, the menu collapse to show the 3 little lines (burger), however when I click the button that used to show the pop down menu, it no longers works.

```
    DIR Structure

    src
       hooks
             userExternalScripts.js

       Routes
             PublicRoutes.js
             PrivateRoutes.js
       Service
             AuthService.js
             internalApp.js

       App.js
       App.css
       Contact.js
       Gallery.js
       Student.js
       Register.js
       Login.js
       index.js
```

Any help would be much appreciated, and please let me know if you need more details.

What I have done so far.

1. Added a hooks directory, and inside created a useExternalScript.js, which adds a script tag containing my script I use to control Navbar as a `src` attribute to the `document.body`.

   *****---------- useExternalScript.js ----------------*****

```
    import { useEffect } from 'react';

    export default function useExternalScripts(){
        useEffect(() => {
            const script = document.createElement("script");

            script.src = "../service/internalApp.js";
            script.async(true);

            document.body.appendChild(script);

            return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
    }, []);
    };
```

2. Added my external script to control Navbar to a service directory

   *****------------------internalApp.js----------------*****

```
    const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu')
    const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu')

    menu.addEventListener('click', function(){
        menu.classList.toggle('is-active')
        menuLinks.classList.toggle('active')
    })
```

3. I have then been attempting to add the below snippet of code, in order to invoke this script, however, I can seem to get it to work.

   I've tried adding it to:
   Home.js,     which is my homepage
   App.js,      which I use to control my routes

   *****------------Snippet of code.---------------*****

```
    import useExternalScripts from "./hooks/useExternalScripts";
    function App() {

    const Component = () => {
        useExternalScripts();
    }
```

4. It would seem that I need to invoke this component somehow, but I am not sure what I should do next.

```
    *****--------------Warning------------------*****

    Line 29:9:   'Component' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars

    *****-----------------------------------------------*****
```

HOME PAGE

```
    import React from "react";
    import Footer from "./Footer";
    import Service from "./Service";
    import Hero from "./Hero";
    import Navbar from "./Navbar";

    const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        {/* <!-- NAV BAR SECTION --> */}
        <Navbar />
    
        {/* <!-- HERO SECTION --> */}
        <Hero />

        {/* <!--Service Section--> */}
        <Service />

        {/* <!--Footer Section--> */}
        <Footer />

        </div>
    );
    };

    export default Home;
```

APP.JS

```
import { BrowserRouter, NavLink, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import Gallery from './Gallery';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Student from './Student';
import Register from './Register';
import Login from './Login';
import PublicRoute from "./routes/PublicRoute";
import PrivateRoute from "./routes/PrivateRoute";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getUser, getToken, setUserSession, resetUserSession } from "./service/AuthService";
import axios from "axios";

//Add this code to try and get Navbar Menu to work with mobile
import useExternalScripts from "./hooks/useExternalScripts";
const Component = () => {
  useExternalScripts();
}
  return (
    <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <div className="header">
                <NavLink exact activeclassname="active" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/gallery">Gallery</NavLink> 
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/student">Student</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/login">Login</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/register">Register</NavLink>
              </div>

              <div className="content">
               <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/gallery" component={Gallery}/>
                <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/student" component={Student}/>
                <PublicRoute exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <PublicRoute exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
              </Switch> 
              </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

NAVBAR

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    // Navbar SECTION
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar__container">
        <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">
          LK Piano
        </a>
        <div className="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul className="navbar__menu">
          <li className="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" className="navbar__links">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar__item">
            <a href="/gallery" className="navbar__links">
              Gallery
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar__item">
            <a href="/contact" className="navbar__links">
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar__item">
            <a href="/student" className="navbar__links">
              Student
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar__btn">
            <a href="/login" className="button">
              Sign up
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: And the navbar itself, is that now rendered in React or is it rendered outside of react (i.e. in the HTML from the server)?

Comment: If it is now *react* rendered you can't do what you are trying to do since React-controlled DOM should never be interfered with by outside scripts. This breaks the rules of react. React is "all-in". You have to commit to using its constructs. If it *is* the case the nav is react-rendered, please show us the nav component so we can help you refactor this behaviour to be react-based.

Comment: However, if the nav is *not* react rendered, then what you are doing is legitimate. Let me know.

Comment: Hey @adsy,

Thank for the reply man, 

I am brand new to web design and self learning, slowly but surely, hahah.   When you say how is the navbar being rendered, I am not sure tbh man,  I guess inside react now,  I will paste a copy of my nav bar below,  i have it in a seperate file, so I can add it to multipe pages,   ill sent a copy of my home page and a snippet of how my redirect work through my App.js file..  Let me kno w if you require any more details man,  been looking at this for days now and cant seem to get it.

Comment: No worries. Posting app.js would be useful. To rephrase my question: is the HTML of the nav (so for example the HTML element with `#mobile-menu` as the ID) defined inside of a React component, or is this part of the actual base HTML page -- i.e. not inside a react component?

Comment: HOME PAGE
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Service from "./Service";
import Hero from "./Hero";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <!-- NAV BAR SECTION --> */}
      <Navbar />

      {/* <!-- HERO SECTION --> */}
      <Hero />

      {/* <!--Service Section--> */}
      <Service />

      {/* <!--Footer Section--> */}
      <Footer />

    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

Comment: Thanks. Could you now post the contents of `Navbar`? Btw, better to edit your original post.

Comment: <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar__container">
        <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">
          LK Piano
        </a>
        <div className="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul className="navbar__menu">

Comment: <NavLink exact activeclassname="active" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/gallery">Gallery</NavLink> 
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/student">Student</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/login">Login</NavLink>
                <NavLink activeclassname="active" to="/register">Register</NavLink>

Comment: <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/gallery" component={Gallery}/>
                <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/student" component={Student}/>
                <PublicRoute exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <PublicRoute exact path="/register" component={Register}/>
              </Switch>

Comment: man,,,  this is kinda messed up, as it wont let me attach many characters,,   is there a way I can attach files?

Comment: Right yeh. I need to see the whole "navbar" JS component, including the entire file it is in. To post this, you need to edit your original post, rather than leave a comment. I already edited your OP also to fix formatting. Notice code blocks are enclosed between 3 backticks either side in edit mode. However, you still have to post code  via editing the original post and not comments. Its not supported in comments.

Comment: Thanks! I see it now. give me some time.

Comment: Hey @adsy,  
just figured out how to use the teardrops for code hahahaha,

Comment: I also have some code in the App.js file, which is connecting to my AWS,, so I have not included this,    do you have all you  need now @adsy?

Comment: @adsy,  I forgot to say,  The Nav Links inside of App.js,  I have hidden these and just use them for routing,   as I already had my Navbar set up in my HTML, if that makes sense.

Comment: Wouldnt that refresh the page every time they are clicked (slower)? `<NavLink>` is hooked into the react router where as an `<a>` tag is not, and will cause a full page refresh during navigation to the next page. What you really want to do is use `<NavLink>` inside your nav component that has the older HTML in it. I can edit my answer further if that makes sense to you. This would mean your page won't even need to refresh when the links are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Now that your Nav is rendered in React, you have to implement all behaviours in React-based code. One of the things about React is that as soon as you change such that some HTML is rendered by React, you have to play by Reacts rules. That comes with a cost and also a learning curve -- which is what you are experiencing right now :).

That means old scripts that sit outside your components and interact with the HTML that was rendered by React, are unfortunately now disallowed.

Essentially, that means if you have old vanilla JS code like your script, you need to rewrite that behaviour using Reacts constructs.

You don't need to load the external script, you need to build the same behaviour in react.

Change your Navbar component to be like follows:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Navbar() {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
  
  return (
    // Navbar SECTION
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar__container">
        <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">
          LK Piano
        </a>
        <div className={`navbar__toggle ${menuOpen ? 'is-active' : ''}`} id="mobile-menu" onClick={() => setMenuOpen(true)}>
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul className={`navbar__menu ${menuOpen ? 'active' : ''}`}>
          <li className="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" className="navbar__links">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar__item">
            <a href="/gallery" className="navbar__links">
              Gallery
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar__item">
            <a href="/contact" className="navbar__links">
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar__item">
            <a href="/student" className="navbar__links">
              Student
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="navbar__btn">
            <a href="/login" className="button">
              Sign up
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

This is the "React way". I have introduced new state to the component, which flips that state to `true` when the `onClick` is called on the `#mobile-menu` element. When that goes true, the needed classes are added to the same components as your old script.

Comment: Hey @adsy,   I can’t thank you enough for taking the time out of ur day to help and to also explain in simple terms.  Really appreciate it mate.    I’m gonging to implement these changes tomorrow and I will let you know how I get on.